# Bitbucket pipeline with multiple branches

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I want to use bitbucket pipelines, and I have bitbucket-pipelines.yml like this:

```
image: java:8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle
          - android-sdk

        script:
          /*SOME CODE*/

          # Build apk
          - chmod a+x ./gradlew
          - ./gradlew assembleDebug

  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          caches:
            - gradle
            - android-sdk

          script:
            /*SOME CODE*/

            # Build apk
            - chmod a+x ./gradlew
            - ./gradlew assembleDebug

          artifacts:
            - app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk

definitions:
  caches:
    android-sdk: android-sdk
```

But there is a lot of equal code in "script", is there any way to fix this? Maybe move equal code to script?

I have trayed move code to build.sh, but got errors:

```
+ ./build.sh
./build.sh: line 4: -: command not found
./build.sh: line 5: -: command not found
./build.sh: line 8: -: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `build.sh` file is a possibility. However, it looks as though you are not removing the '-' character when you copy the commands of the script to your file. For the file given, your `build.sh` should looks like:

```
/* SOME CODE*/

# Build apk
chmod a+x ./gradlew
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Note how there is no '-' before each command.
Your bitbucket-pipelines.yml file should then look like:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle
          - android-sdk

        script:
          - ./build.sh

  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          caches:
            - gradle
            - android-sdk

          script:
            - ./build.sh

          artifacts:
            - app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk

definitions:
  caches:
    android-sdk: android-sdk
```